# Linux Mint 20 with LUKS and LVM hangs on boot after upgrade

Tags: ubuntu, boot, lvm, luks, cryptsetup

**Solution**

I've solved the problem by adding the `initramfs` flag in `/etc/crypttab` and using `keyscript=decrypt_keyctl` instead of a keyfile to avoid entering the password two times for the second drive:

```
luksSSD UUID=[UUID1]    none    luks,initramfs,discard,keyscript=decrypt_keyctl
luksHDD UUID=[UUID2]    none    luks,initramfs,keyscript=decrypt_keyctl
```

Afterwards `update-initramfs -c -k all` needs to be executed and the problem is solved.

---

Recently I've upgraded from Linux Mint 19.3 to 20.1 (with 20.0 as a step between). So now I am using Linux Mint 20.1 based on Ubuntu 20.04. My system is using two hard drives. They are encrypted using LUKS and contain a LVM VG.

On both hard drives there is a PV:

```
sudo pvs -v
  PV                  VG   Fmt  Attr PSize   PFree   DevSize  PV UUID                               
  /dev/mapper/luksHDD vglp lvm2 a--   <1,73t 266,62g   <1,73t [PV UUID1]
  /dev/mapper/luksSSD vglp lvm2 a--  463,89g   3,89g <463,90g [PV UUID2]
```

My crypttab is the following:

```
luksSSD UUID=[UUID1]    none    luks,discard
luksHDD UUID=[UUID2]    none    luks
```

On booting the computer I first get the following error message:

```
  Volume group "vglp" not found
  Cannot process volume group vglp
  Volume group "vglp" not found
  Cannot process volume group vglp
```

This happened already before the upgrade too.

Afterwards I am immediately asked for the password (the same for both volumes). Then the system was just booting without any problems before the upgrade.

But now it hangs for several seconds (about 20 seconds). Afterwards the following error message appears and the system hangs for roughly 1 minute:

```
  WARNING: Couldn't find device with uuid I[PV UUID1].
  WARNING: VG vglp is missing PV [PV UUID1] (last written to /dev/mapper/luksHDD).
  WARNING: Couldn't find device with uuid [PV UUID1].
  WARNING: VG vglp is missing PV [PV UUID1] (last written to /dev/mapper/luksHDD).
```

<strike>After this minute it just boots without any additional problems. I don't know where `/dev/mapper/luks-hdd-neu` comes from. I never used this path nor can I find it any file in `/etc/`.</strike>

Does anybody know why the boot process is hanging here. Why is the second PV not found first but then found later without problems?

Edit: After I run `update-initramfs -c -k all` instead of `update-initramfs -u -k all` the error message doesn't contain this weird `/dev/mapper/luks-hdd-neu` anymore and contains the right path. However, the system still hangs on boot.

Thanks in advance!